# nginx proxy_pass wildcard config

Tags: nginx

I have a apache configuration like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPass /app http://localhost:8080/app
    ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost:8080/app
    ProxyPass /images http://localhost:8080/app/images
    ProxyPassReverse /images http://localhost:8080/app/images
</VirtualHost>
```

I am trying to translate this to nginx config. So far I have

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/app;
    }

    location /app/images {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/app/images;
    }
    ...
}
```

This is a lot of repetition. Please help me figure out how to have just one location that would handle all sub-paths also. In addition I would like to not enable any (wildcard) sub-paths, but a set of known ones. Say, I want to enable `localhost/app`, `localhost/app/images`, and no others. Just like above but shorter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nginx allow having regexp for matching location, assuming you might need `index.html`. Otherwise just remove it.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location ~ ^/app/(index.html|images)? {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a `location` block like this:

```
location /app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

When the `proxy_pass` contains no path component, nginx will append the normalized URI of the request to the host part of `proxy_pass` directive.